# dandelion datatables spring mvc runtime themeoption

Tags: spring-mvc, themes, datatables, jquery-ui-theme, dandelion

I am trying to use jqueryui themes in dandelion [datatables](http://datatables.net). So I started with this [link](http://dandelion.github.io/datatables/docs/ref/configuration/#themeoptions). But, can we pass `themeoption` at runtime?

```
<datatables:table id="users" data="${list}" row="user"
     rowIdBase="userId" rowIdPrefix="person_"  pageable="true" displayLength="5"       
     filterable="true"  processing="true" autoWidth="true" 
     theme="jqueryui" 
     themeOption="<spring:theme code="theme"/>"
```

or

```
<datatables:table id="users" data="${list}" row="user"
     rowIdBase="userId" rowIdPrefix="person_"  pageable="true" displayLength="5"       
     filterable="true"  processing="true" autoWidth="true" 
     theme="jqueryui" 
     themeOption="<c:out value="theme"/>"
```

I want to use the spring theme. I am using `themeResolver` and `themeChangeInterceptor`. Will the theme of `datatables` change when I will change the theme?

In my `theme-default.properties` file

```
css=themes/blue/style.css
theme=start
```

My theme names are `default`, `green`, `orange`, `purple`, and `red`.

`datatables`'s themes I want to use are `start`, `southstreet`, `humanity`, `peppergrinder`, and `flick` respectively.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All tag attributes accept Runtime Expression values.

Maybe you should try the following syntax:

Example 1:

```
<spring:theme code="theme" var="springTheme" />
<datatables:table id="users" data="${list}" row="user"
     rowIdBase="userId" rowIdPrefix="person_"  pageable="true" displayLength="5"       
     filterable="true"  processing="true" autoWidth="true" 
     theme="jqueryui" 
     themeOption="${springTheme}">
     ...
</datatables:table>
```

Example 2:

```
<datatables:table id="users" data="${list}" row="user"
     rowIdBase="userId" rowIdPrefix="person_"  pageable="true" displayLength="5"       
     filterable="true"  processing="true" autoWidth="true" 
     theme="jqueryui" 
     themeOption="${theme}">
    ...
</datatables>
```

*(Disclaimer required by StackOverflow: I'm the author of Dandelion)*

Comment: Example 1 worked for me... Great thanks... Can you please suggest me any theme for `red` color css???

Comment: Also tell me how can I use custom theme if I want to do so.... Thank you in advance....

Comment: Dandelion-Datatables support all themes from [ThemeRoller](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/) through the combo: theme="jqueryui" / themeOption="sunny", for example [docs here](http://dandelion.github.io/datatables/features/styling/themes/jqueryui.html).

Comment: How can I apply my own theme downloaded from http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/ named `Purpletheme`??

Comment: Please create another question for that ;-)

Comment: I created it, please see here ->> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24032270/dandelion-datatables-custom-jqueryui-theme

Comment: Hi Please provide solution to my pagination problem... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37748231/dandelion-datatables-spring-mvc-pagination-disables-if-pipelining-is-false