# Dandelion Datatables Custom jqueryUI theme

Tags: spring, jquery-ui, themes, datatables, dandelion

Recently I integrated [datatables](http://dandelion.github.io/datatables/) with my `spring 4 mvc` + `Hibernate 4` + `Tiles 3` Project.

Everything is working fine. But I have one issue. My `jqueryUI themes` are not working properly.

Please have a look in below images. 
1. `Search filter` and `export links` are not in one row. I want them to appear in one row.

I tried with `dom="ilfrtip"` Export links disappeared!! Also did not get output what I wanted...!

[image]

2. And `datatable sorted column` appears **blue** in all themes !!

[image]

3. I also want to highlight row on mouse hover as shown [here](http://datatables.net/examples/styling/hover.html), but with my **custom color** not blue.
4. I also want stripes as shown [here](http://datatables.net/examples/styling/hover.html), but with my custom colors.

I used  `cssStripes="odd,even"`, but not working. :(

So I want to apply custom theme instead of basic [themeoptions](http://dandelion.github.io/datatables/docs/ref/configuration/#themeoptions) themes.

I have downloaded my custom theme from [ThemeRoller](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/) name `PurpleTheme`.

How can I apply this to `datatables`?

I am loading themes from spring theme properties using spring `themeresolver` and `themeinterceptor`.

```
<spring:theme code="theme" var="springTheme" />
<datatables:table id="users" data="${list}" 
row="user" rowIdBase="userId" rowIdPrefix="user_"  
displayLength="5" lengthMenu="5,10,15,25,50,100"
jqueryUI="true" theme="jqueryui" themeOption="${springTheme}" 
filterable="true" 
processing="true" autoWidth="true" 
pageable="true" paginationType="full_numbers" 
export="csv,xml,pdf,xls,xlsx" stateSave="true" deferRender="true"   >
```

Any help is invited. Thank you in advance.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just made a test by downloading a theme from [ThemeRoller](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/).
Here follows the required steps to apply a custom theme using Dandelion & Dandelion-Datatables v0.10.0.

### 1/ Download and install the jQueryUI-related assets

Once you've downloaded all assets from ThemeRoller, place them inside your project. In my example, I use the following standard Maven architecture:

```
src
|__ main
   |__ webapp
      |__ assets
         |__ css
            |__ jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.css
         |__ images
            |__ ui-bg_*****.png
            |__ ui-icons_****.png
```

*Warning:* I had to update all image links in the CSS file to point them to my `images` folder (`../images/` instead of `images/`).

### 2/ Prepare a new asset bundle

Once all assets are here, create a new [bundle](http://dandelion.github.io/dandelion/features/asset-bundles/introducing-asset-bundles.html) called `custom-theme.json` in the `src/main/resources/dandelion` folder.

In this file, you just need to reference your custom CSS. Don't forget to mark this bundle as dependent of the `jqueryui` one (which is already activated when you use the `theme="jqueryui"` table attribute).

```
{
    "bundle" : "custom-theme",
    "dependencies": [ "jqueryui" ],
    "assets": [{
        "name": "jquery-ui-custom",
        "version": "0.10.0",
        "type": "css",
        "locations": {
            "webapp": "/assets/css/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.css"
        }
    }]
}
```

### 3/ Create an extension for Dandelion-Datatables

Currently, the only way to use a custom theme option for the `jqueryui` theme is to create an extension.

In order to alleviate the configuration (JSP-side), I suggest you to create an extension (actually a theme), that will activate both jQueryUI and your custom theme, so that you don't need to use `theme="jqueryui"` any longer.

**3.1/ Create a class that extends `AbstractExtension`**

```
package com.example;

public class CustomJqueryTheme extends AbstractExtension {

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "myTheme";
    }

    @Override
    public void setup(HtmlTable table) {

        // Activate bundles
        AssetRequestContext
            .get(table.getTableConfiguration().getRequest())
                .addBundle("ddl-dt-theme-jqueryui")
                .addBundle("custom-theme");

        // Add "bJQueryUI":true
        addParameter(DTConstants.DT_JQUERYUI, true);

        // Add class="display"
        table.addCssClass("display");
    }
}
```

**3.2/ Register your extension**

Then, your extension must be detected by Dandelion-Datatables. To do so, you must define the `[group].main.extension.package` property in the configuration file. This property is actually a package where Dandelion-Datatables will scan for extensions.

So I added a new `datatables.properties` file under the `src/main/resources/dandelion/datatables/` folder, which contains:

```
global.main.extension.package=com.example
```

### 4/ Activate the extension

Once the ground prepared, you can test your extension by activating it thanks to the `ext` table attribute.

```
<datatables:table ... ext="myTheme" ...>
    ...
</datatables:table>
```

Just pass the name you have given above in the `getName()` method of your extension.

### 5/ Adapt the configuration

It works well without export links. But as soon as you activate the export feature, Dandelion-Datatables will update the sDom parameter with a new letter: `E` (for Export), therefore breaking the configuration previously set by the jQuery theme.

So you just need to override this setting as follows:

```
<datatables:table ... ext="myTheme" export="csv" dom="<\"H\"lEfr>t<\"F\"ip>">
    ...
</datatables:table>
```

Another option would be to configure the sDom parameter directly in the above `CustomJqueryTheme` Java class.

Finally, if you want to update the odd/even rows, just use the cssStripes table attribute as follows:

```
<datatables:table ... cssStripes="css-class-for-odd,css-class-for-even">
    ...
</datatables:table>
```

Just ensure:

- either to use something different than "odd" and "even" (because Datatables use these classes)
- or if you still want to use "odd" and "even", make sure to override them with custom CSS rules.

---

As you can see, it's not very easy. :-/

But it should become a bit simpler in upcoming versions thanks to improvements in the extension mechanism.

Note that I'll update this answer once this example will be available in the official Dandelion-Datatables sample applications.

*(Disclaimer required by StackOverflow: I'm the author of Dandelion)*

Comment: Is there any way that I can specify custom theme in `themeOption`?

Comment: How can I remove this css?? which appears in all pages. `<link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.4/css/jquery.dataTables.css"/>`

Comment: Using the Dandelion-Core taglib: 
`<dandelion:asset cssExcludes="datatables"/>`
Don't forget to declare the taglib before:
`<%@ taglib prefix="dandelion" uri="http://github.com/dandelion" %>`